# write to file within a for loop - python

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate over JSON and write to a file as the information is retrieved. My code looks like this

```
for i in range(100):
    identifier = data ['items'][i]['id']
    out_file.write(identifier)
```

When I run it I get an indent error on the out_file.write line. I have seen so much code formatted in this way and I'm baffled as to why it isn't working for me. If I make the out_file line even with the for line, the program works, but only writes the last identifier in the loop. Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An indent error means that the indents don't line up.  You should make sure that the line `out_file.write(identifier)` lines up with `identifier = data ['items'][i]['id']`, and that you *don't mix up tabs with spaces*.

Comment: ... and if you demoted out_file.write all the way to left margin, it would fire after the loop had completed and only write one value - exactly what you're seeing.

Comment: Thank you. You are all quite right. The issue in my particular case was that I had some trailing tabs that were screwing things up. I think the lesson learned here is that when there are mysterious indentation errors to show the invisible characters to make sure everything is what you think it is.